# Decorate Renderer

Tags: jsf

I want to add a HTML5 attributes to simple text inputs. Therefore I'd like to decorate the standard Renderer for h:inputText. My solution is based on inheriting from com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.TextRenderer which is specific to Mojarra. Is there a better way to decorate an existing Renderer without tying to a specific implementation and without having to re-implment functionality of the basic renderer?

Here is my solution so far:

```
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily=Html5InputRenderer.COMPONENT_FAMILY, rendererType=Html5InputRenderer.COMPONENT_TYPE)
public class Html5InputRenderer extends TextRenderer {

public static final String COMPONENT_FAMILY = "javax.faces.Input";

public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "javax.faces.Text";

public static final String RENDERED_TYPE_NAME = "renderedType";

@Override
public void encodeBegin(final FacesContext context, final UIComponent component) throws IOException {

    if (component.getAttributes().containsKey(RENDERED_TYPE_NAME)) {

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();

        String replacement;

        try {
            ResponseWriter clonedWriter  = writer.cloneWithWriter(buffer);
            context.setResponseWriter(clonedWriter);
            super.encodeBegin(context, component);

            String renderedMarkup = buffer.toString();

            // do some stuff with markup rendered by the basic renderer

            clonedWriter.close();

            if (null != replacement) {
                writer.write(replacement);
            }

        } finally {
            context.setResponseWriter(writer);
        }

    } else {
        super.encodeBegin(context, component);
    }
}
```

Thx, DS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decorate renderers by [providing your own render kit](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/RenderKitWrapper.html#getRenderer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). To do this, create a [`RenderKitFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/render/RenderKitFactory.html) with a public constructor that takes an argument of type `RenderKitFactory`. Define the new `RenderKitFactory` in a `faces-config.xml`. During initialization, the JSF framework will pass the previously configured `RenderKitFactory` to your constructor.

See the [JSF spec](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) for more details.

Comment: I see. I could use both the original RenderKitFactory and RenderKit to obtain an instance of the original Renderer. And then just delegate rendering to the Renderer instance. Thx, that should do the trick.